# Python regex not working in code

Tags: python, regex

I've uploaded it here..

http://regex101.com/r/hC2eH3/1

Let email.body =

```
> From: "FastTech" <support@fasttech.com>
>
> == Ship to ==
> Example Name
>
> Shipping via Registered Airmail w/Tracking
>
> == Shipping ETA ==
>
> == Items ordered ==
>
> == Other services ==
>
>
> == Order total ==
> $2.63
>
>
>
>
> Thank you again for choosing FastTech.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> The FastTech Team
>
>
> FastTech - gadget and electronics
> http://www.fasttech.com
> support@fasttech.com
>
>
> This email was automatically generated for
```

I can't get this to work in my script - using this code:

```
    regex = r'> == Ship to == *\n. (\w+\s\w+)'
    link = re.findall(regex, email.body)
    print link
```

print link just returns

[]

When it should be matching 'Example Name'

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Your problem is in email.body. The regex works fine. Try printing the email.body. To see its real value

Comment: That regex works correctly here on a copy & pasted version of your `email.body`. So maybe you have string encoding issues that get magicked away when you post the `email.body` here.

Comment: Eg, your regex will have problems if any of those spaces are actually non-break space = `\xa0`, or if your end-of-line marker is `\r` or `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works fine for me.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """> From: "FastTech" <support@fasttech.com>
... >
... > == Ship to ==
... > Example Name
... >
... > Shipping via Registered Airmail w/Tracking
... >
... > == Shipping ETA ==
... >
... > == Items ordered ==
... >
... > == Other services ==
... >
... >
... > == Order total ==
... > $2.63
... >
... >
... >
... >
... > Thank you again for choosing FastTech.
... >
... > Kind regards,
... >
... > The FastTech Team
... >
... >
... > FastTech - gadget and electronics
... > http://www.fasttech.com
... > support@fasttech.com
... >
... >
... > This email was automatically generated for """
>>> m = re.findall(r'> == Ship to == *\n. (\w+\s\w+)', s)
>>> m
['Example Name']
```

**OR**

You may try this. A single space would match exactly a space where `\s*` would match zero or more spaces. So it's better to use `\s*` instead of a space.

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'^\s*>\s*==\s*Ship\s*to\s*==\s+>\s*(\w+\s\w+)', s, re.M)
>>> m
['Example Name']
```

Comment: This works... why doesn't mine? Thanks for the answer :-) it was my first attempt at a regex..

Comment: @Andy it may or maynot contain one or more spaces.. You're always welcome :-)